# ESRI - Arcmap help to create a button that will populate current date for selected features

Tags: vbscript, esri, arcobjects

I would like to create a custom tool or button in Arcmap that programmatically fills in a number of attributes of selected features for a layer.
To keep things simple, lets say my Arcmap project only has one SDE layer, and I'd like to populate the Date_Created field.
The SDE layer being edited is versioned.

I have some code that partially works, but after the selected records are updated, the layer can no longer draw stating it's in a closed State.

[link text](http://www.vimeo.com/14973022)

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.
Thanks,
Frank

Comment: You might also try posting on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this behavior may be related to management of the edit operations in your script.

Any edit operations that you start must either be stopped (completed) or aborted. If no features have been edited, the edit operation needs to be aborted.